# Equation for Angle Around an Ellipse given semi-major (a), semi-minor (b), and length of radius (r)?

Tags: conic-sections, angle

What is the equation to find the angle $\theta$ around an ellipse if given only horizontal semi-axis $a$, vertical semi-axis $b$, and just a ***length for radius $r$***? I've also attached an image that graphically shows the problem.

[image: Angle Around Ellipse Graphic Representation of Problem]

I'm stuck trying to rearrange and isolate $\theta$ for solving using the equation:

$$r = \frac{ab}{\sqrt{a^2\sin^2\theta+b^2\cos^2\theta}}$$

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

$$ r^2(a^2\sin^2\theta+b^2\cos^2\theta)=a^2b^2;$$
$$ r^2(a^2\sin^2\theta+b^2(1-\sin^2\theta))=a^2b^2;$$
Let $\hat a = a/r$ and $\hat b=b/r$
$$ \hat a ^2\sin^2\theta+\hat b^2(1-\sin^2\theta)=\hat a^2 \hat b^2;$$
$$ (\hat a ^2-\hat b^2)\sin^2\theta+\hat b^2=\hat a^2 \hat b^2;$$
$$ (\hat a ^2-\hat b^2)\sin^2\theta=(\hat a^2-1) \hat b^2;$$
$$ \sin^2\theta=\frac{(\hat a-1)(\hat a+1) \hat b^2}{(\hat a+\hat b)(\hat a-\hat b)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Polar equation of the ellipse is
$$r=\frac{a b}{\sqrt{a^2 \sin ^2(t)+b^2 \cos ^2(t)}}$$
which can be reduced to
$$r =\frac{\sqrt{2} a b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+(b^2 -a^2)\cos (2 t)}}$$
Solving wrt $t$ we get
$$\cos(2t)=\frac{a^2 r^2+b^2 r^2-2 a^2 b^2}{r^2 \left(a^2-b^2\right)}$$
and then
$$t = \frac{1}{2}\,\arccos\left(\frac{a^2 r^2+b^2 r^2-2 a^2 b^2}{r^2 \left(a^2-b^2\right)}\right)$$

The ellipse has four points with the same $r$-value. This formula only gives the angle of the point in the first quadrant, with both coordinates positive.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Let $F_1,F_2$ be the foci of the ellipse,
$|OA|=|OC|=|BF_1|=|BF_2|=a$,
$|OB|=b$, $\angle DOA=\theta$,
$|OD|=r$, $|DF_2|=u$, $|DF_1|=v$.

We know that
\begin{align}
|OF_1|=|OF_1|&=\sqrt{a^2-b^2}
\tag{1}\label{1}
,\\
u+v&=2a
\tag{2}\label{2}
.
\end{align}

By the
[Stewart’s Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart%27s_theorem)

\begin{align} 
\triangle F_1F_2D:\quad
|DF_1|^2\cdot|OF_2|+
|DF_2|^2\cdot|OF_1|
&=|F_1F_2|\cdot(|OD|^2+|OF_1|\cdot|OF_2|)
\tag{3}\label{3}
,\\
(u^2+v^2)\sqrt{a^2-b^2}&=2\sqrt{a^2-b^2}\,(r^2+a^2-b^2)
\tag{4}\label{4}
,\\
u^2+v^2&=
2(r^2+a^2-b^2)
\tag{5}\label{5}
.
\end{align}

Combination of \eqref{2} and \eqref{5} gives

\begin{align} 
uv&=2a^2-\tfrac12(u^2+v^2)
\tag{6}\label{6}
,\\
uv&=a^2+b^2-r^2
\tag{7}\label{7}
.
\end{align}

A pair of equations \eqref{2}, \eqref{7} results in

\begin{align} 
u&=a-\sqrt{r^2-b^2}
\tag{8}\label{8}
,\\
v&=a+\sqrt{r^2-b^2}
\tag{9}\label{9}
,
\end{align}
since $u<v$ by construction.

Given that, we have all the side lengths of $\triangle OF_2D$
in terms of known values $a,b,r$,
and the angle  $\theta$ now can be found
by the cosine rule:

\begin{align} 
\theta&=\arccos\left(\frac ar\sqrt{\frac{r^2-b^2}{a^2-b^2}}\right)
\tag{10}\label{10}
.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

For easy calculation... if reciprocals of $(a,b,r)$, are  computed as $(a',b',r')$ then for non-circular ellipses

$$ \frac{\cos2 \theta }{2}= \dfrac { (2 r'^2 - a'^2  - b'^2)}{(a'^2-b'^2)}$$

which solve to four angles.